# List of `to do's` with chapter AND section, and skipping ch/sect without to do's

Tags: table-of-contents, luatex, tocloft

I have defined a command for the *to do's*:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools,etoolbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amstext} % for \text macro
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\newcommand{\addchaptertotoctodos}{\relax}
\newcommand{\addsectiontotoctodos}{\relax}

\newcounter{TotTodos}
\newcommand{\listtodosname}{List of to do's (\arabic{TotTodos})}
\newlistof{todos}{todo}{\listtodosname}
\newcounter{todo}[chapter]
\newcommand\todo[1]{
\refstepcounter{todo}
\phantomsection
\label{todo:\thechapter.\thetodo}\stepcounter{TotTodos}
\textcolor{red}{To do \thetodo} \textcolor{gray}{#1}
\addchaptertotoctodos
\renewcommand{\addchaptertotoctodos}{\relax}
\addcontentsline{todo}{todos}
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter.\thetodo} #1}
}

% change the cmd chapter to add the chapterts to the list of todo's
\makeatletter
\let\ori@chapter\@chapter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ori@chapter[#1]{#2}%
  \if@mainmatter\renewcommand{\addchaptertotoctodos}{\addcontentsline{todo}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}{#1}}}%
  \else\renewcommand{\addchaptertotoctodos}{\addcontentsline{todo}{chapter}{#1}}%
  \fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\todo{a}

\section{Section 1.1}
\todo{b}
\section{Section 1.2}
\todo{c}

\section{Section 1.3}

\chapter{Middle chapter}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\section{Section 2.1}
\todo{d}

\section{Section 2.2}

\section{Section 2.3}
\todo{e}

\chapter{Last chapter}

\cleardoublepage % assure start with odd page number
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of to do's}
\listoftodos

\end{document}
```

This command works fine, generating a list of *to do's* organized per chapters. I tried to enhance it to list *in addition* the sections, but changing `chapter` with `section` was not enough.

> I would like to enhance the code in such a way that
>
> 1. chapters and sections are listed in the index of to to's
> 2. <s>chapters and sections are not printed if there is no to do' under them (the command for the addition of the chapter /section line to the `todos` toc should be saved somewhere and only executed by the first occurrence of a *to do*)</s> done

Here is also a picture of the actual PDF:
[image: List of todos]

The result should be

```
List of to dos (5)

1 First chapter
1.1 a
1.1 Section 1.1
1.2 b
1.2 Section 1.2
1.3 c

2 Second chapter
2.1 Section 2.1
2.1 d
2.3 Section 2.3
2.2 e
```

**EDIT 1** The point (2) is solved and the code in the question has been actualized. Open is only the addition of the section.

Comment: Perhaps unrelated, but you're loading `hyperref` ways too early

Comment: Suggestion: `texdoc todonotes`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer were should it be? at the end? what are the consequences?

Comment: @Fran thank you for the hint, but the package (besides the dependencies) does not even structures the to do's in chapter, my main goal

Comment: The tricky bit is NOT listing the chapters and sections without todos.  Basically, you need to check the current chapter and section against the last one listed, THEN list (\addcontentsline) the new chapter and/or section.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I do not have the technical knowlegde to do it, but my idea is to 1) modify the chapter so that a command \addlinetotocforchapter is defined 2) modify the section so that a command \addlinetotocforsection is defined 3) in the todo command just execute \addlinetotocforchapter and \addlinetotocforsection and redefine both with a empyt operation. Something like that would do the job.

Comment: Every time you list a chapter or section, save the value in a (new) counter or global macro.  (Initialize to 0.)  `\ifnum\value{chapter}=\value{lastchapter}\relax\else \setcounter{lastchapter}{\value{chapter}} \setcounter{section}{0} ... \fi`

Comment: @JohnKormylo I've edited the question with the simple trick I sketched and it works. I now only need to know how to adapt the section, which seems not to behave like the chapter.

Comment: BTW, that should have been `\setcounter{lastsection}{0}`, or you could just define `\newcounter{lastsection}[lastchapter]`